# Deviations from group mean by id

Tags: r, indexing, data-manipulation, data-cleaning, centering

I have some data where time is nested within individuals:

```
set.seed(124)
x = rnorm(25)
data.frame(id=rep(1:5, each=5), time=1:5, x=x)
```

What would be a base R solution to append a column that calculates deviations of each observation from the same person's average across time (i.e., centering around the person’s mean)? The output should look like this (x.c is the appended column that calculates the deviations from the person's mean):

```
   id time           x           x.c
1   1    1 -1.38507062  3.814056e-07
2   1    2  0.03832318  1.423394e+00
3   1    3 -0.76303016  6.220408e-01
4   1    4  0.21230614  1.597377e+00
5   1    5  1.42553797  2.810609e+00
6   2    1  0.74447982  2.233398e-08
7   2    2  0.70022940 -4.425040e-02
8   2    3 -0.22935461 -9.738344e-01
9   2    4  0.19709386 -5.473859e-01
10  2    5  1.20715377  4.626740e-01
11  3    1  0.31833673  2.642477e-08
12  3    2 -1.42379885 -1.742136e+00
13  3    3 -0.40509086 -7.234276e-01
14  3    4  0.99538657  6.770499e-01
15  3    5  0.95881779  6.404811e-01
16  4    1  0.91808790 -3.680049e-09
17  4    2 -0.15096960 -1.069058e+00
18  4    3 -1.22306879 -2.141157e+00
19  4    4 -0.86882429 -1.786912e+00
20  4    5 -1.04248536 -1.960573e+00
21  5    1 -1.10363778  2.169331e-07
22  5    2  0.44418506  1.547823e+00
23  5    3 -0.20495061  8.986874e-01
24  5    4  1.67563243  2.779270e+00
25  5    5 -0.13132225  9.723158e-01
```

I know the `tidyverse` solution is `group_by` but I would like a base R solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `base R` solution would be to get the mean by 'id' with `ave` and subtract from the individual observations of 'x'

```
df1$x.c <- with(df1, x - ave(x, id))
```

Comment: @akrun. Need help. Why does my code returns a different column ? `df1 <- merge(df, aggregate(x ~ id, data = df, mean), 
      by = "id", suffixes = c("", "mean"))

df1$x.c <- df1$x - df1$xmean`.

Comment: @TarJae I get the same values from your output and mine.  The expected output showed in the OP's may not be the correct one

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative base R approach using `aggregate`:

```
df1 <- merge(df, aggregate(x ~ id, data = df, mean), 
      by = "id", suffixes = c("", "mean"))

df1$x.c <- df1$x - df1$xmean
df1[-4]
```

```
   id time           x        x.c
1   1    1 -1.38507062 -1.2906839
2   1    2  0.03832318  0.1327099
3   1    3 -0.76303016 -0.6686435
4   1    4  0.21230614  0.3066928
5   1    5  1.42553797  1.5199247
6   2    1  0.74447982  0.2205594
7   2    2  0.70022940  0.1763090
8   2    3 -0.22935461 -0.7532751
9   2    4  0.19709386 -0.3268266
10  2    5  1.20715377  0.6832333
11  3    1  0.31833673  0.2296065
12  3    2 -1.42379885 -1.5125291
13  3    3 -0.40509086 -0.4938211
14  3    4  0.99538657  0.9066563
15  3    5  0.95881779  0.8700875
16  4    1  0.91808790  1.3915399
17  4    2 -0.15096960  0.3224824
18  4    3 -1.22306879 -0.7496168
19  4    4 -0.86882429 -0.3953723
20  4    5 -1.04248536 -0.5690333
21  5    1 -1.10363778 -1.2396192
22  5    2  0.44418506  0.3082037
23  5    3 -0.20495061 -0.3409320
24  5    4  1.67563243  1.5396511
25  5    5 -0.13132225 -0.2673036
```